# Prevent Internet download manager to catch and download videos from server side

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, video-streaming, video.js, http-live-streaming

I am developing a video sharing web site, in this web site I segmented my MP4 files in multiple ts files.

For Playing videos in browser I use videoJs plugin and for playing segmented files in videoJs I use videojs-contrib plugin.

I use asp.net mvc for server side.

What I want is to prevent users and Internet Download Manager any any other download manager to catch and download my video files.

I like to have Youtube functionality, is there a way to achieve this ?

this is my master playlist :

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=528384,RESOLUTION=480x270,CODECS="avc1.42001e,mp4a.40.2"
http://****/videos/2017/2/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab-240.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=249856,RESOLUTION=256x144,CODECS="avc1.42001e,mp4a.40.2"
http://****/videos/2017/2/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab-144.m3u8
```

i have two format for my sample, and for i show 240p format playlist

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:15
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXTINF:10.023222,
http://****/videos/2017/2/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab-240-00000.ts
#EXTINF:11.466667,
http://****/videos/2017/2/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab-240-00001.ts
#EXTINF:11.233333,
http://****/videos/2017/2/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab-240-00002.ts
#EXTINF:10.300000,
http://****/videos/2017/2/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab-240-00003.ts
#EXTINF:7.300000,
http://****/videos/2017/2/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab-240-00004.ts
#EXTINF:10.066667,
http://****/videos/2017/2/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab-240-00005.ts
#EXTINF:10.633333,
http://****/videos/2017/2/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab-240-00006.ts
#EXTINF:9.633333,
http://****/videos/2017/2/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab-240-00007.ts
#EXTINF:10.900000,
http://****/videos/2017/2/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab-240-00008.ts
#EXTINF:8.533333,
http://****/videos/2017/2/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab/da2ce797-09ae-463b-a0dc-897ea28517ab-240-00009.ts
```

maybe i have to set some settings in IIS or in my server side code or in videoJs plugin.

Interesting thing about Internet Download Manager is that it is wise enough to concat ts files into a single ts file. I would like to prevent idm from doing this also.

Comment: What you are asking is not possible. The server doesn't know if you are downloading and playing, or downloading and storing. What you are looking for is DRM. You can use HLS drm in browser, you must use common encryption.

Comment: @szatmary can you provide me links or some keywords so that i can check on ?

Comment: Try searching for `DRM` and `Common Encryption`